# How can I run 'npm i' in a Jenkins Maven build?

Tags: maven, jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

I have a Jenkins job set up so that whenever I have a GitHub pull request triggered, the Jenkins pipeline will run an 'npm i' for all the node dependencies (with my registry set to a Nexus repository), and then running a 'mvn install' for my maven build. In my Jenkins pipeline script, my npm install goes something like:

```
stage ('NPM') {
         steps {
             dir('git_workspace') {
                  sh 'npm set registry http:<myHostName>/nexus/content/repositories/npm-central/'
                  sh 'npm i'
              }
         }
    }
```

However, when the pull request triggers a build, it fails halfway through the 'npm i' command with an error that is usually something like:

```
npm ERR! code E500
npm ERR! 500 Server Error - GET http://<MyHostName>/nexus/content/repositories/npm-central/@typescript-eslint/scope-manager/-/scope-manager-4.33.0.tgz
```

Except the package that it fails on installing is usually different each time. I have a theory that between my npm i and nexus, there is some kind of connection timeout. Does anyone know how this can be fixed or worked around?

Comment: Are you creating the agent that the pipeline is running on?